# Materialized view for calculated results

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table like below, where State is a limited set of updates (e.g. Start, End):

```sql
CREATE TABLE event_updates (
  event_id Int32,
  timestamp DateTime,
  state String
) ENGINE Log;
```

And I want to be able *quickly* run queries like:

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
 SELECT event_id,
  minOrNullIf(timestamp, state = 'Start') as start,
  minOrNullIf(timestamp, state = 'End') as end,
  end - start as duration,
  duration < 10 as is_fast,
  duration > 300 as is_slow
 FROM event_updates
 GROUP BY event_id)
WHERE start >= '2020-08-20 00:00:00'
AND start < '2020-08-20 00:00:00'
AND is_slow;
```

But those queries are slow when there is a lot of data, I'm guessing because the calculations are required for every row.

Example data:

```sql
┌─event_id─┬───────────timestamp─┬─state─┐
│        1 │ 2020-08-21 09:58:00 │ Start │
│        1 │ 2020-08-21 10:18:00 │ End   │
│        2 │ 2020-08-21 10:23:00 │ Start │
│        2 │ 2020-08-21 10:23:05 │ End   │
│        3 │ 2020-08-21 10:23:00 │ Start │
│        3 │ 2020-08-21 10:24:00 │ End   │
│        3 │ 2020-08-21 11:24:00 │ End   │
│        4 │ 2020-08-21 10:30:00 │ Start │
└──────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

And example query:

```sql
SELECT
    event_id,
    minOrNullIf(timestamp, state = 'Start') AS start,
    minOrNullIf(timestamp, state = 'End') AS end,
    end - start AS duration,
    duration < 10 AS is_fast,
    duration > 300 AS is_slow
FROM event_updates
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY event_id ASC

┌─event_id─┬───────────────start─┬─────────────────end─┬─duration─┬─is_fast─┬─is_slow─┐
│        1 │ 2020-08-21 09:58:00 │ 2020-08-21 10:18:00 │     1200 │       0 │       1 │
│        2 │ 2020-08-21 10:23:00 │ 2020-08-21 10:23:05 │        5 │       1 │       0 │
│        3 │ 2020-08-21 10:23:00 │ 2020-08-21 10:24:00 │       60 │       0 │       0 │
│        4 │ 2020-08-21 10:30:00 │                ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │     ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │    ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │    ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└──────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

What I would like to produce is a pre-calculated table like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE event_stats (
  event_id Int32,
  start Nullable(DateTime),
  end Nullable(DateTime),
  duration Nullable(Int32),
  is_fast Nullable(UInt8),
  is_slow Nullable(UInt8)
);
```

But I can't work out how to create this table with a materialized view or find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I would

1. use [MergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/)-engine instead of Log to get benefits from sorting key

```sql
CREATE TABLE event_updates (
  event_id Int32,
  timestamp DateTime,
  state String
) ENGINE MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(timestamp)
ORDER BY (timestamp, state);
```

2. constraint the origin dataset by applying WHERE-clause to *timestamp* and *state* (in your query processed the whole dataset)

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM (
 SELECT event_id,
  minOrNullIf(timestamp, state = 'Start') as start,
  minOrNullIf(timestamp, state = 'End') as end,
  end - start as duration,
  duration < 10 as is_fast,
  duration > 300 as is_slow
 FROM event_updates
 WHERE timestamp >= '2020-08-20 00:00:00' AND timestamp < '2020-09-20 00:00:00' 
    AND state IN ('Start', 'End')
 GROUP BY event_id
 HAVING start >= '2020-08-20 00:00:00' AND start < '2020-09-20 00:00:00' 
   AND is_slow);
```

---

If these ones don't help need to consider use [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree/) to manipulate the precalculated aggregates not raw data.